# How do I prevent other applications from connecting to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have a Delphi application connecting to a remote SQL Server via ADO components.

How can I allow **only** my application access to SQL Server 2012 and any other application trying to connect should be thrown out?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that everything that connects to SQL Server does this by a ConnectionString.

If you really want, you can intercept those, and use them to fake to be another application.

As long as applications cannot in one way or the other use digital signatures to connect, there is no way to enforce what you want.

Comment: I agree with this summary.  As long as someone can create a connection string, and pass along valid authentication credentials, any application will gain access to the SQL Server Database, as well as potentially any roles and granted permissions that the supplied user id would normally gain.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Logon trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) and in this trigger compare `APP_NAME()` with a constant containing your application name. If they are different, then perform `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: how do you pass the APP_NAME to the sql server?

Comment: See [APP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) connection parameter.

Comment: Thanks, and +1. that's what I thought... I still think that this is kinda pointless, since if I have the connection string, I could use it in another application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Application Role](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10182/working-with-application-role-sql-server.aspx) of SQL Server.

For me it makes no sense to lock whole SQL Server with Logon Trigger. There could be other databases and it should be also free for e.g. SQL Agent or for Management Studio or for Update-Program...

If you want to control access to database - use Users' and Application Roles. By App. Role you should call one stored procedure from your compiled code, and than all you can do will be defined by Application Role. If you disable access for other roles and users, nobody can access your database... Other databases could be also configured to give no permissions to other users/roles.

It makes more sense, has no problem with connection string and is flexible for other tasks.

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.